# Evaluating $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How would you evaluate the following series?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} $$

Thanks.

Comment: Maple says $\pi/2$

Comment: It looks like you might be able to interpret the summand as a Riemann sum ...

Comment: @ Michael Joyce: Yeah. That's true. Anyway, I'm interested in more approaching ways if possible.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Recall that for any decreasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and any $N>1$ we have
$$
\int\limits_1^{N+1}f(x)dx\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}f(k)\leq \int\limits_0^N f(x)dx
$$
After substitutions $N=n^2$, $f(x)=n/(n^2+x^2)$ and simple computations we have
$$
\arctan\frac{n^2+1}{n}-\arctan \frac{1}{n}\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}\leq\arctan n
$$
Lets take a limit $n\to\infty$, then from sandwich lemma it follows
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

P.S. First solution was not rigor enough.

Comment: How is the decreasing function property called?

Comment: @REr, decreasing

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $$\int_0^a f(x) dx \approx \sum_{k=0}^{na} \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$ Use $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Addendum:
Fortunately, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing, therefore the error is bounded by $\frac{f(0)-f(a)}n$, which again is $<\frac1n$, independent of $a$. This last observation allows us to use $a=n$ without spoiling convergence to $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$.

Comment: With $a=n$, the approach becomes unconventional and seems to require some further analysis.

Comment: @did: I believe you're right. I've tried to add the necessary analysis to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Using $x=k/n$ and $\mathrm{d}x=1/n$
$$
S_m(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{mn}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{mn}\frac{1}{1+(k/n)^2}\frac1{\vphantom{k^2}n}\tag{1}
$$
is a Riemann Sum for
$$
I_m=\int_0^m\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\tag{2}
$$
For any $m$ and $n$, we have
$$
\sum_{k>mn}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}\le\sum_{k>mn}\frac{n}{k(k-1)}=\frac1m\tag{3}
$$
which implies that
$$
S_m(n)\le S_\infty(n)=\lim_{m\to\infty}S_m(n)\le S_m(n)+\frac1m\tag{4}
$$
Since
$$
I_\infty=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}I_m=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\tag{5}
$$
for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $m_\epsilon\ge\frac1{\large\epsilon}$ so that for $m\ge m_\epsilon$,
$$
I_\infty-\epsilon\le I_m=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_m(n)\le I_\infty\tag{6}
$$
Finally, there is an $n_\epsilon\ge m_\epsilon$ so that for $n\ge n_\epsilon$,
$$
I_\infty-2\epsilon\le S_{m_\epsilon}(n)\le I_\infty+\epsilon\tag{7}
$$
Since $m_\epsilon\ge\frac1{\large\epsilon}$, $(4)$ and $(7)$ yield that for $n\ge n_\epsilon$
$$
I_\infty-3\epsilon\le S_n(n)\le I_\infty+2\epsilon\tag{8}
$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we get that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n(n)=I_\infty\tag{9}
$$
which translates to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n^2}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=\frac\pi2\tag{10}
$$

Comment: Nice and detailed (+1)

Comment: @Chris'sister: This looks deceptively like a reference to Riemann Sums, but since the upper index is $n^2$, we have to handle the improper integral carefully.

Comment: @ robjohn: Right. And this is because m is not fixed, but it tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach.

First, note that
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=n^2+1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}
&<& \sum_{k=n^2+1}^\infty \frac{n}{k^2} \\
&\le& n\int_{n^2}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} \\
&=& \frac{1}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
We also need the [partial fraction expansion of $\coth x$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36#E3),
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\coth x &=& \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{x-i k \pi} \\
&=& \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2+k^2\pi^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Then we find 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} - \sum_{k=n^2+1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}
\right) \\
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} \\
&=& \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\coth n\pi - \frac{1}{2n}\right) \\
&=& \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: @Chris'sister: Sometimes life gets in the way! [Aigner and Ziegler](http://books.google.com/books?id=KvQr9l0wgf8C&lpg=PA127&ots=v0e0VPu8cf&dq=partial%20fraction%20expansion%20of%20cot&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q=partial%20fraction%20expansion%20of%20cot&f=false) have a nice derivation of the partial fraction expansion for $\cot x$ in *Proofs from The Book* (see *Cotangent and the Herglotz trick*). I tend to think of such sums in terms of complex analysis.

Comment: yeah, nice! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n^{2}}{n \over n^{2} + k^{2}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n^{2}}{n \over n^{2} + k^{2}}}&=
> -\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{n^{2}}{1 \over k + \ic n}
> =-\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{n^{2} - 1}{1 \over k + 1 + \ic n}
> \\[3mm]&=-\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{%
> {1 \over k + 1 + \ic n} - {1 \over k + n^{2} + 1 + \ic n}}
> \\[3mm]&=-n^{2}\,\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
> {1 \over \pars{k + n^{2} + 1 + \ic n}\pars{k + 1 + \ic n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#c00000}{%
> \Im\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 + \ic n} - \Psi\pars{n^{2} + 1 + \ic n}}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).
>   $\ds{z \in {\mathbb C}\verb=\=\braces{0,-1,-2,\ldots}}$. We'll use the property $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \approx \ln\pars{z}}$ when $\ds{\verts{z} \gg 1}$
>   and $\ds{\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}} < \pi}$.

Then,
\begin{align}\color{#00f}{\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n^{2}}{n \over n^{2} + k^{2}}}&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\Im\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 + \ic n} - \Psi\pars{n^{2} + 1 + \ic n}}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}
\Im\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + \ic n} - \ln\pars{n^{2} + 1 + \ic n}}
\\[3mm]&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\arctan\pars{n} - \arctan\pars{n \over n^{2} + 1}}
=\color{#00f}{\large{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We have the following important theorem,

> **Theorem**: Let for the monotonic function $f$ ,$\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx$ exists and we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ then
>   we have
>
> $$\lim_{h\to0^+}h\sum_{v=0}^\infty f(vh)=\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx$$

It is enough to take $h^{-1}=t$ and $f(x)=\frac{2}{1+x^2}$, then we get the desired result.

> So we showed that
>   $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{t}+\frac{2t}{t^2+2^2}+\cdots+\frac{2t}{t^2+n^2}+\cdots\right)=\pi$$

Let me show some additional infinite sum by this theorem

> We show
>
> $$\lim_{t\to
>  1^{-}}(1-t)^2\left(\frac{t}{1-t}+\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2}+\frac{3t^2}{1-t^2}+\cdots
>  \frac{nt^2}{1-t^2}+\cdots\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Now in previous theorem if we take $e^{-h}=t$ and $f(x)=\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}$ then since

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{xe^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\int_0^\infty x(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx})dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

The previous theorem gives us an important relation of infinite sum about Euler constant

> We show
>
> $$\lim_{t\to
>  1^{-}}(1-t)\left(\frac{t}{1-t}+\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}+\frac{t^3}{1-t^3}+\cdots \frac{t^n}{1-t^n}+\cdots\right)-\log\frac{1}{1-t}=C=\text{Euler
>  constant}$$

By using the previous theorem we just need to take $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$ and $e^{-h}=t$ and since it is known that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=C=\text{Euler constant}$$

See this book for more examples of G.polya, problems and theorems in analysis , vol  I  Springer