# How should we evaluate such questions on limit of summation?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

Can someone please show me how to do such questions with necessary steps..$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{6n}{9n^2-k^2}$$

I have seen a similar question, ([Evaluating $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190966/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n2-fracnn2k2) ) but couldn't understand the method used for solving. Thank you

Comment: The terms within the summation, should be of the form, (1/n)*f(k/n) where k runs from 1 to n. After that, it can be evaluated in the form of an integral. Refer to conversion of limit of  sum as an integral.

Comment: @SrinathPrasad thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{6n}{9n^2-k^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{6n}{9n^2-k^2}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{6}{9-(\frac{k}{n})^2}=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n}) =  \int_0^1f(x)dx \, where\, f(x)= \frac{6}{9-x^2}$